# join query result in "Call to a member function leftJoin() on null"

Tags: laravel, join, controller, query-builder

I am trying to run a join query from my controller on laravel but i am getting "Call to a member function leftJoin() on null"

```
public function tracking_groupindividual(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->user_id;
    $group_id = $request->group_id;

    $get_group_individual_details = DB::table('group_usermapping as gu')
        ->select(
           'um.user_id', 
           'um.user_name', 
           'um.image_path', 
           'um.mobile_number', 
           'ul.latitude', 
           'ul.longitude', 
           'um.isnearby_on', 
           'gu.isadmin', 
           'um.profile_status', 
           'ul.timedout'
        )
        ->join('user_master as um','gu.user_id','=','um.user_id')
        ->join('groupusers_location as ul','ul.user_id','=','um.user_id','ul.group_id','=','gu.group_id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($group_id) {
            $query->where('gu.group_id', '=', $group_id)
                ->where('gu.isactive','=','1')->where('um.isactive','=','1');
        })->get();

        return $get_group_individual_details;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in the second join and fixed it

```
public function tracking_groupindividual(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->user_id;
    $group_id = $request->group_id;

    $get_group_individual_details = DB::table('group_usermapping as gu')
        ->select(
           'um.user_id', 
           'um.user_name', 
           'um.image_path', 
           'um.mobile_number', 
           'ul.latitude', 
           'ul.longitude', 
           'um.isnearby_on', 
           'gu.isadmin', 
           'um.profile_status', 
           'ul.timedout'
        )
        ->join('user_master as um','gu.user_id','=','um.user_id')
        ->join('groupusers_location as ul', function ($join) {
            $join->on('ul.user_id','=','um.user_id')
                ->where('ul.group_id','=','gu.group_id');
        })
        ->where(function ($query) use ($group_id) {
            $query->where('gu.group_id', '=', $group_id)
                ->where('gu.isactive','=','1')->where('um.isactive','=','1');
        })->get();

        return $get_group_individual_details;
    }
```

Comment: getting the same error now on select "Call to a member function select() on null" @Morteza Rajabi

Comment: Using use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB for importing DB class in my controller

Answer (score 0):

**try to use DB::raw() with aliases!!!**

```
$get_group_individual_details = DB::table(DB::raw('group_usermapping as gu'))
                                ->join(DB::raw('user_master as um'),DB::raw('gu.user_id'),'=',DB::raw('um.user_id'))
                                ->join(DB::raw('groupusers_location as ul'),DB::raw('ul.user_id'),'=',DB::raw('um.user_id'),DB::raw('ul.group_id'),'=',DB::raw('gu.group_id'))
                                ->select(DB::raw('um.user_id'),DB::raw('um.user_name'),DB::raw('um.image_path'),DB::raw('um.mobile_number'),DB::raw('ul.latitude'),DB::raw('ul.longitude'),DB::raw('um.isnearby_on'),DB::raw('gu.isadmin'),DB::raw('um.profile_status'),DB::raw('ul.timedout'))
                                ->where(function ($query) use ($group_id) {
                                        $query->where(DB::raw('gu.group_id'), '=', $group_id)->where(DB::raw('gu.isactive'),'=','1')->where(DB::raw('um.isactive'),'=','1');
                                         })->get();

return $get_group_individual_details;
```

and replace **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;** with **use DB**;